# Flickering animation with UIViewAnimationTransitionFlip

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios-simulator, uianimation

I have a containerview with 2 subviews. I want to flip from one to another. The problem is that some kind of flickering appears. It doesn't happen on the iPhone 3GS, but on the Simulator and the iPhone 3G:
http://www.hanspinckaers.com/upload/Flickering.png

Does anyone know why this happens?

This is the code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.75];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationProceed)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.containerView cache:YES];

if(self.mapViewController.view.superview){      
    [self.mapViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.tableController.view];
} else {
    [self.tableController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.mapViewController.view];
}


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks in advance!

Hans

Comment: http://www.hanspinckaers.com/upload/Flickering.zip , here you can see it happen.

Answer (score 4):

fyi flickering usually happens when you have 2+ seperate caanimations working, try to put them all into a single animation block and commit the groups animations.

Comment: This gives me hint of how to fix one flicking I encountered thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem but I do get issues if the tableview or mapview is scrolling when the transition starts.

Perhaps disabling user interaction and stopping any scrolling etc just before doing the transition will help?

Apart from that, sorry!

Sam

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't work. I'm going to make a project file with this problem and will post it later this day. Maybe it's something with the size of the frame? I really don't know.

Comment: Added a project file where it happens.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this problem?  I'm having a similar one.